# Why doesn't my application release files on .close() so they can be deleted?

Tags: java, resources

My problem is that during an XML import of text data into my application (javafx), a file(s) is created through an OutputStream of bytes from the XML, stored in a 'temp' folder, flushed and closed but they cannot be deleted unless the application is closed.

This is a fairly simple deletion code. I do .flush() and .close() the files after creation. They are not opened, just simply created. The application navigates to the 'temp' folder and deletes all files within. The deletion code works in independent testing but not while the application is running. I think the delete code is fine, the problem is getting the files to be released. I've researched that I'm properly creating and closing the file(s) and the deleting code seems simple enough. So I'm not sure why they are still not released for deletion.

This code creates the file(s) and writes them to a 'temp' folder location. This is an array for each file name and a string of file data converted to bytes which creates the file(s):

```java
        String[] ary = f.split("\\*", 2);
        OutputStream os = null;
        try {
            String filePath = GlobalVariables.TEMP + ary[0];
            byte[] bytes = ary[1].getBytes();
            os = new FileOutputStream(new File(filePath));
            os.write(Base64.getDecoder().decode(bytes));
            os.flush();
            os.close();
            files.add(new NoteFile(ary[0], filePath));
        } catch(IOException io) {
            io.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if(os != null) os.close();
                System.gc();
            } catch(IOException io){
                LoggerWrapper.getInstance().myLogger.fine("ResearchController.loadImportedDataToDB cannot release files");
            }
        }
```

This code "attempts" to delete the files contained in the 'temp' folder during clean up if there were files contained in the XML.

```java
if(n.containsKey("File")){
    File file = new File(GlobalVariables.TEMP);
    String[] myFiles;
    if(file.isDirectory()){
        myFiles = file.list();
        for (String s : myFiles) {
            File myFile = new File(file, s);
            myFile.delete();
        }
    }
}
```

The purpose is to be able to share information and files between users of this application. So, files are imported/exported through XML using Base64. On import, files are created and closed -- and at the user's discretion, attached and stored as byte data in a database. After the files are stored in the database, then the application is to clean up (delete) the files stored in a 'temp' folder regardless.

Comment: Note you can use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to greatly simplify your code.

Comment: @Slaw - Good suggestion, I did try it but I still get the same issue. I still cannot delete the files in the directory without closing the application.

Comment: From what you've shown I'm not sure why that's the case. Create a [mre] that demonstrates the issue. The operating system and Java version you're using might also be significant.

Comment: looks unrelated to fx

Comment: Sorry for late response, been OOO. I minimized the first block to just what is being done with the xml file data. An array with a 'filename' [0] separated by '*' (asterisk) then string of file data [2]. The files is created and stored in a temp folder -- never opened. The second block should delete when this temp file is no longer needed but it can't. I'm using Java 1.8.202 and Intellij IDEA 2018.1.1 with Windows 10 Pro

Comment: Correction, the file data string (byte string) is position [1] in the file array. (e.g. filename[0], filedata[1]).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I embarrassingly solved my problem. What I posted actually works correctly above.

The actual cause was during the writing and File Streaming of the byte data to the database, the File Stream was not being closed after completion. After closing the File Stream (fis) the issue was resolved.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
for(int readNum; (readNum=fis.read(buf))!=-1;)
     bos.write(buf,0,readNum);
fis.close();                  // This was the missing code which corrected my issue.
return bos.toByteArray();
```